# Problemas com impressão de array

Tags: java

Matriz Principal:

```
public static String [][] matrizPrincipal(){
        String [] [] matriz = new String [2] [6];
        matriz[0][0] = "Robin Arryn";
        matriz[0][1] = "Lino Facioli";
        matriz[0][2] = "145";
        matriz[0][3] = "Vivo";
        matriz[0][4] = "Arryn";
        matriz[0][5] = "Feminino";
        
        matriz[1][0] = "Yohn Royce";
        matriz[1][1] = "Rupert Vansittart";
        matriz[1][2] = "45";
        matriz[1][3] = "Vivo";
        matriz[1][4] = "Arryn";
        matriz[1][5] = "Feminino";
        return matriz;
    }
```

Método que seleciona o nome dos personagens que são Femininos e estão na família Arryn:

```
public static String imprimeMatrizFeminina(String [] [] mat){
        int cont = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<mat.length; i++){
            if(mat[i][5].equals("Feminino") && mat[i][4].equals("Arryn")) cont ++;
        }
        String[] matrizFemininaArryn = new String [cont];
        for(int i=0; i<mat.length; i++){
            if(mat[i][5].equals("Feminino") && mat[i][4].equals("Arryn")) matrizFemininaArryn[i] = mat[i][0];
            System.out.println("Mulheres da família Arryn:" + Arrays.toString(matrizFemininaArryn));
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Parte da main que chama esse método:

```
case 6:
                String matrizMulheres = imprimeMatrizFeminina(mat);
                System.out.println(matrizMulheres);
                break;
```

Alguém sabe me dizer porque está ocorrendo isso?

[image: http://puu.sh/hQUAf/aa3a16bc7a.png]

A segunda impressão está correta, mas porque ocorre a primeira?

**DETALHE:** Vou ter que fazer uma impressão para cada família no mesmo método, por isso não estou utilizando o return. Ou seja, todos os Femininos, separados pelas familias.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido.
Era só mover o `println` para fora do `for`

Comment: Marque o V que está embaixo do campo de votação da resposta. Isso vai indicar que essa resposta resolve o problema.